# 403 on Android for Reddit API but not on browser

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, reddit

When making a request with Retrofit using an OKHttp Client with interceptors to add headers:

(Authorization: Bearer + access_token)
(User-Agent: "user_agetn_as_described_by_reddit")

Using the oauth.reddit.com/.json URL as recommended by Reddit, I get a 403. Now, when I do this same thing on Postman or something similar, I get a 200 and the expected JSON.

Is anyone aware of something related to Android or Retrofit or OKHttp that could be causing me this pain?

Comment: I suggest you to proxy your requests (android/postman) so that to compare the two requests and see their differences. That’s the best way to debug http request and have a deep insight of them.

Comment: @shadowsheep I made a mistake when the token retrieval. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the auth code instead of the access_token to make my requests. A mistake from my side. You should use the auth code to make a token request.

Comment: Was my hint helpful? BTW I’m glad to know you’ve found what was wrong ;-)